# AWS Lambda "Unable to import module" with Zipped Dependencies

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am trying to upload a python lambda function with zipped dependencies but for some reason I am constantly getting

```
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'CreateThumbnail'"
```

whenever I test it.

Here are the steps I took which were almost identical to [these docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python).

1. Created and activate a virtualenv with `virtualenv ~/lambda_env` and `source ~/lambda_env/bin/activate`
2. Install Pillow and boto3 with `pip install Pillow` and `pip install boto3`
3. Zip dependencies with `cd $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and `zip -r9 ~/CreateThumbnail.zip *`
4. Add the actual python lambda function to the zip file with `zip -g ~/CreateThumbnail.zip CreateThumbnail.py` where `CreateThumbnail.py` is

   ```
   from __future__ import print_function
   import boto3
   import os
   import sys
   import uuid
   from PIL import Image
   import PIL.Image

   s3_client = boto3.client('s3')


   def resize_image(image_path, resized_path):
       with Image.open(image_path) as image:
           image.thumbnail(tuple(x / 2 for x in image.size))
           image.save(resized_path)


   def handler(event, context):
       for record in event['Records']:
           bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
           key = record['s3']['object']['key']
           download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
           upload_path = '/tmp/resized-{}'.format(key)

           s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
           resize_image(download_path, upload_path)
           s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, '{}resized'.format(bucket), key)
   ```
5. Then in the console I set the handler to be `CreateThumbnail.handler`
6. Then I upload `CreateThumbnail.zip` via the aws console and click 'save & test' I get

`"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'CreateThumbnail'"`

I am very confused by this because feel like I am following the docs.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check out the lambda-uploader project... It handles the packaging of dependencies and is config based.

- https://github.com/rackerlabs/lambda-uploader/

Also these links may be helpful:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html
- https://markn.ca/2015/10/python-extension-modules-in-aws-lambda/
- http://www.perrygeo.com/running-python-with-compiled-code-on-aws-lambda.html

Comment: Thanks, I just tried lambda-uploader with `"requirements": ["Pillow","boto3"]` in lambda.json but unfortunately I get the same error `"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'CreateThumbnail'"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the packaging hierarchy. After you install the dependencies, zip the lambda function as follows (in the example below, lambda_function is the name of my function)

Try this:

```
pip install requests -t .
zip -r9 lambda_function.zip .
zip -g lambda_function.zip lambda_function.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not let your browser automatically unzip the lambda "project" file after downloading. This seems to corrupt the file when it is re-zipped and used.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you pointed out uses **python 3.8**

[image]

And you seem to be using **python 2.7**

That may be the reason.

---

I am doing a [similar tutorial](https://amazon.qwiklabs.com/focuses/10541?parent=catalog), but they give us the zip ready to upload but warning to select python 3.7 and not 3.8 or it will fail to run correctly.